# Docusign customtags are blank in template from API call

Tags: apex, docusign

I have a Template created in DS which contains custom tags which are mapped to Salesforce fields. The template works well when used via the JS button example code provided by DS and the fields appear as expected.

I am now trying to automate the process using the Docusign SOAPAPI. When creating the envelope the custom fields aren't populated; even the signer fields.

Below is my code:-

```
DocusignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1 recipients = new DocusignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1(); 
    recipients.Recipient = new list<DocusignAPI.Recipient>();
    DocusignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocusignAPI.Recipient();
    recipient.Email = signer_email;
    recipient.UserName = signer_name;
    recipient.ID = 1;
    recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
    recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
    recipients.Recipient.add(recipient);

    DocusignAPI.ArrayOfTemplateReference templateReferences = new DocusignAPI.ArrayOfTemplateReference();
    templateReferences.TemplateReference = new list<DocusignAPI.TemplateReference>();
    DocusignAPI.TemplateReference templateReference = new DocusignAPI.TemplateReference();
    TemplateReference.Template = '6bc2930f-6d46-4804-a9fc-69d1cf3ebe09';
    templateReference.TemplateLocation = 'Server';
    templateReferences.TemplateReference.add(templateReference);


    DocusignAPI.EnvelopeInformation ei = new DocusignAPI.EnvelopeInformation();
    ei.AccountId  = account_id;
    ei.Subject = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    ei.EmailBlurb = 'More text...';
    // Create an envelope and fill it in

    DocusignAPI.CustomField field = new DocusignAPI.CustomField (); 
    field.Name = 'DSFSSourceObjectId'; 
    field.Value = 'a1qW0000000vMCj';
    field.Show = 'false';
    field.CustomFieldType = 'Text';
    DocusignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField arrayOfCustomFields = new DocusignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField();
    arrayOfCustomFields.CustomField  = new list<DocusignAPI.CustomField>();
    arrayOfCustomFields.CustomField.add(field);

     ei.CustomFields = arrayOfCustomFields;

    try {
            DocusignAPI.EnvelopeStatus result = api_sender.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(templateReferences, recipients, ei, true);

        envelope_id = result.EnvelopeID;
        System.debug('Returned successfully, envelope_id = ' + envelope_id );
    } catch ( CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
        error_code = 'Problem: ' + e;
        error_message = error_code;
    }
```

All customtags are related to my custom object with id defined in the CustomField above.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Is this still an issue that needs answering? If not, can you please post your resolution below as an answer.